# Allow users to decide the number of input

Tags: pysimplegui

I am new to PySimpleGUI and I want to create a APP that allow users to input the number of input. For example, when users input 3 in the input box, interface will generate another 3 input boxes to carry 3 input. How I did it is that I close the old window and create a new one after button is clicked. It functions well, but the issue is after the second window is done, the interface can't hold and crash, saying old window is a Nonetype. Is there any solution for this or for generating input boxes? Thanks in advance

Comment: Any simple code to demo your issue ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.